# the mediaPlayer in my timer keeps crushing the app

Tags: java, android

when i run this code :

```
package com.example.eggtimer;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView timeLft;
    SeekBar timer;
    public void start(View view) {
        CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timer.getProgress() * 1000 + 100, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                updateTimer((int) l / 1000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Log.i("state", "done");
                MediaPlayer hi = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.sound);
                hi.start();
            }
        }.start();
    }
        public void updateTimer(int secLft) {
            int min = secLft/60;
            int sec = secLft - (min*60);
            String secS = Integer.toString(sec);
            if (sec <= 9) {
                secS = "0" + sec;
            }
            timeLft.setText(Integer.toString(min) + ":" + secS);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        timer = findViewById(R.id.timer);
           timeLft = findViewById(R.id.timeLft);
        timer.setMax(600);
        timer.setProgress(30);

        timer.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                updateTimer(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

without the mediaPlayer the code runs ok, but when i run it with the mediaPlayer it crushs, and these errors appear in the run section :

**E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.eggtimer, PID: 10017
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/raw/sound.MP3 from drawable resource ID #0x7f0c0000
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.openRawResourceFd(ResourcesImpl.java:296)
at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:1292)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:965)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:948)
at com.example.eggtimer.MainActivity$1.onFinish(MainActivity.java:27)
at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:127)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetFdNative(Native Method)
at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetFd(AssetManager.java:487)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.openRawResourceFd(ResourcesImpl.java:294)
at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResourceFd(Resources.java:1292) 
at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:965) 
at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:948) 
at com.example.eggtimer.MainActivity$1.onFinish(MainActivity.java:27) 
at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:127) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)**

what does this mean?

Comment: `Resources$NotFoundException: File res/raw/sound.MP3`

Comment: sound.mp3 resource not found by compiler

Comment: make sure mp3 file present there

Comment: it is present in the raw file.

Comment: i changed the format frim .mp3 to m4a, and now the app does crash, but doesn't play the sound either even after changing the name.

Comment: update : the doesn't crash, but the audio doesn't play.

Comment: The right thing to do, is to try re-uploading the file to the raw folder.